# Cannot access Jenkins web page remotely on mac

Tags: macos, jenkins, homebrew, macos-sierra, launchd

I had the same exact problem as mentioned by another user [here](http://www.azeitler.me/jenkins-on-os-x-connection-refused/). Summary: installed and using Jenkins on macOS Sierra using homebrew. Running as a LaunchAgent daemon via the 'brew services start jenkins' command. Everything works fine and can access the Jenkins web page via the default port of 8080 on the mac where it's running. However, accessing it via any other computer on the LAN results in a "Connection refused" error. Tried the suggested comment in the linked blog post above about adding the Sockets section to the homebrew.mxcl.jenkins launchd plist homebrew creates, but that didn't help either.

What **did** make it accessible from a remote computer was changing the Jenkins --httpListenAddress param in the launch plist from the default 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0. My question is why did that work? Why did that make the Jenkins web page accessible from a remote computer? Also, why would this be the default for the [jenkins homebrew formulae](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/ba4118c7b07f9da1b5eb6553f57e29234afee428/Formula/jenkins.rb) if it causes this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest: I'm not a mac or homebrew user.

But if you check the jenkins documentation for [Starting and Accessing Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins) you will find the following documentation for the `--httpListenAddress` :

> Binds Jenkins to the IP address represented by $HTTP_HOST. The default is 0.0.0.0 — i.e. listening on all available interfaces. For example, to only listen for requests from localhost, you could use: --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1

Most propably the homebrew contributors thought it wouldn't be a good idea to provide a remote accessible jenkins instance by default. They rather provide a *local* jenkins only accessible from *localhost*.

Comment: Thanks! I agree with your thoughts; I also agree with editors that suggested this be moved to the Server Fault site. That site already had this answer - my bad for not knowing it existed